# GoLang put string in map

Tags: string, go

So, I'm trying to add a string to an existing map that is created from toml.

http://hastebin.com/vayolavose

When I try and build I get the error:

./web.go:56: arguments to copy have different element types: []proxy.Address and string

How would I go about converting it? I've been trying this for the past like 4 hours.

Thanks

Comment: If your question is about your code, include it in the question, don't post it on another site. If the coDe is too long, only post the relevant part(s). Create a minimal, complete, verifiable example: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

while,the code below is your source code

```
func handleAddFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
backend := r.FormValue("backend")
key := r.FormValue("key")
if !isAuthorized(key) {
    respond(w, r, 403, "")
    return
}
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain")
if !readConfig() {
    return
}

activeAddrs = make([]proxy.Address, len(config.Proxy.ServerAddrs))
backendAddr = make([]proxy.Address, len(backend))
copy(backendAddr, config.Proxy.ServerAddrs)
copy(backendAddr, backend)
loadBalancer.SetAddrs(backendAddr)
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Input value of ", backend, "and here is the byte",      backendAddr)

}
```

your code's error, is  `copy(backendAddr, backend)`, variable backend is a string value from the request from, you may change this into `[]proxy.Address`, such as (consider I donnot know the struct of proxy.Address ):

```
var backendAddr = []proxy.Address{}
for _,str := range strings.split(backend,","){
         backendAddr = append(backendAddr, &proxy.Address(str))
}
```